# establecer initialState Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Estoy intentado establecer el initialState de redux desde mi base de datos

```
const persistedState = loadState().then(res => { return (res) });

console.log(persistedState)

const store = createStore(
    allReducers
);
```

En la función loadState hago la llamada al endpoint con axios

```
async function getDataDB() {
    const header = {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
    }
    return await Axios.get('http://localhost:4000/state/', header)
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es persistedState el console.log(persistedState),no sé como acceder al valor donde se guarda el array para guardarlo en el state y después recorrerlo con un map desde un componente

Comment: al ser una promesa los valores resueltos estan en el `then`. Si haces el `console.log(res)` en el `then` veras los datos que devuelve la api.

Comment: sí, los muestra, pero no me sirve mostrarlos, tengo que usarlos en el store

Comment: nose como tienes implementado el store pero cuando te llegan los datos de la api no puedes despchar una acción que te setee el nuevo estado? O sea en el `then` hacer algo asi `store.dispath(newState)`;

Comment: lo probé pero me sigue dando lo mismo de la imagen anterior

Comment: lo que hice fue usar el localStorage para guardar el valor y después lo utilizo y me funciona, de todas formas seguiré mirando porque no me gusta del todo como queda

Comment: tienes configurado redux-thunk?

Comment: no, pero lo voy a mirar